# Define a variable based on other condition when it is true

Tags: apex, community

```
public static String urlJWT {
        get {
            List <Community_Experience_Settings__mdt> exp =  [SELECT Click_Custom_Magic_Link_Extension__c, Experience__c 
                                                            FROM Community_Experience_Settings__mdt 
                                                            WHERE Click_Custom_Magic_Link_Extension__c = true AND Experience__c =: expidVal LIMIT 1];
            if(exp.size() > 0 && !exp.isEmpty() && String.isBlank(urlJWT) && !String.isBlank(usernameVal)){
                String language = [SELECT LanguageLocaleKey FROM User WHERE Username =: usernameVal LIMIT 1].LanguageLocaleKey;
                    urlJWT = expidVal +'/logmein?token=' + GenericCommunityJWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeVal) + '&lang='+language;
                return urlJWT;
            } else { 
                    urlJWT = expidVal + '/logmein?token=' + GenericCommunityJWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeVal) + '&lang=en_GB';
                return urlJWT;
                    } 
                }
        set;
    }
```

Click_Custom_Magic_Link_Extension__c returning tru or false. I want to define a new variable and check if Click_Custom_Magic_Link_Extension__c is true and then pass expidVal of true condition ti the beginning of urlJWT.

In other words 'if Click_Custom_Magic_Link_Extension__c is true add its expidVal to the beginning. If not true do not add anything (be empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your [other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344238/check-if-specific-field-of-list-is-true), you are looking at the wrong value. `Click_Custom_Magic_Link_Extension__c` will *always* be true in returned records because you are specifically querying for records where it is true.

The important question seems here to be whether or not the list is empty, which you are already checking for. You simply need to change your `else` clause to omit `expidVal` if you don't want it to be used there.