# Check if specific field of list is True

Tags: apex

```
    List <carsToSell__mdt> tesla =  [SELECT broken__c, unique__c 
FROM carsToSell__mdt 
WHERE broken__c = true AND unique__c =: numberID LIMIT 1];
```

I want to check if element of broken__c is True.

I tried (if tesla.broken__с[0] == True) but if fails

Comment: `Broken__c` is a field, not a list. It has no elements. All returned metadata records are guaranteed to have `broken__c` as True because of your query. Can you step back and explain why you're trying to do this?

Comment: @DavidReed because of my previous question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344228/define-a-variable-based-on-other-condition-when-it-is-true

Answer (score 2):

`Broken__c` is a field, not a list. It has no elements.

You *could* access the first element of the list `tesla` and evaluate *that record's* value for `Broken__c`, but *doing so would achieve nothing*. All returned metadata records are guaranteed to have `broken__c` as `True` because of your query:

```
WHERE broken__c = true
```

That means checking the value of `broken__c` will *always* return `True`, and you're just wasting lines of code and CPU time.

You can check whether or not your query actually returned anything by writing logic against `tesla.size()`.